# Данные по клику не передаются в попап в Reacte.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь передать в попап данные по кликнувшей карточке, но поля инпута не заполняются. Что можно сделать в такой ситуации?

Что делаю, передаю в папап объект того типа:

```
ID: 91, CreatedAt: "2020-09-23T23:03:38.923387Z", UpdatedAt: "2021-06-04T15:27:13.297903Z", DeletedAt: null, Type: {…}, …}
CreatedAt: "2020-09-23T23:03:38.923387Z"
DeletedAt: null
ID: 91
Polls: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
Type: {ID: 11, CreatedAt: "2020-07-24T20:36:00.685Z", UpdatedAt: "2021-06-04T15:27:13.295919Z", DeletedAt: null, EventsTypeName: "Дискотека", …}
UpdatedAt: "2021-06-04T15:27:13.297903Z"
days: "monday"
description: ""
is_active: true
lat: 0
lng: 0
logo: ""
name: "фывф"
price: "0"
start_time: undefined
```

Далее с помощью useEffect обновляю стейт

```
React.useEffect(() => {
      setDataForm({
        discoteca: schedule.name,
        address: schedule.description,
        time: schedule.start_time,
        price: schedule.price,
        avatar: schedule.logo,
        day: {value: schedule.days},
        is_active: schedule.is_active,
      })
    }, []);
```

но при этом данные в стейт не парсятся, он выглядит так
[image: но при этом данные в стейт не парсятся, он выглядит так]

как можно передать данные, чтоб их можно было отредактировать?

Comment: Добавьте код как вы передаете данные.

Comment: Евгений, а как его залить сюда?

Comment: Но так объект туда прилетает пропсом. А ещё горят ошибки на форму, что мол я изменил компонент с управляемого на нуупрааляеиый

Comment: добавь полноценный пример(минимизированный(лишние детали каторые не касаются проблемы убери)) да и где функция клик?